# How to order selected files by selected order in Tkinter filedialog?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**I want to select multifiles and order them by selected order**

my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk,filedialog

def selectfile():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('0x0+0+0')
    root.withdraw()
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='Open',multiple=True)
    root.destroy()
    return file_path
```

> selected `file_3` `file_1` `file_2`

> output is `file_1` `file_2` `file_3`

Comment: I thought I had a solution by removing the multiple tag from `askopenfilenames` so that when you select files it does not sort them. However as soon as you press `Open`, it returns it as a sorted list. Annoying!!

Comment: again ,return sorted list :(